# how can I redirect to another page passing data but without a post in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

When users come to my page `_mypage.aspx?querystring_` I don't want the query string to remain in the address bar, because I don't want to repeat the action that relies on that value if they refresh.
I was trying to get the value from the query string and post it to the same page, but it gives pretty much the same effect: refreshing will repost.

I was trying to redirect adding the value to the hash (#), but hash value doesn't get back to the server.

What are my options? How can I redirect to another or same page without a post, but keeping the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somehow applicable to what your after, I'd execute the action when you get the request with the querystring, and at the end you redirect to an url (the same) without the querystring (Post-Redirect-Get).

However, you could also use a **cookie**:

1. Server receives querystring url
2. Server sends redirect response to the url without querystring, adding a cookie containing the querystring
3. Server receivers URL without querystring, but with cookie
4. Server executes action based on cookie-value, removes cookie and sends final response displaying action results.

A refresh of the page will not have the cookie anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If you are within your same website, you can use [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to store data.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["asdf"] = someObject;
```

It is stored as an object, so you will have to cast it appropriately.

Comment: More on Session:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx
There are other (better) ways to do this, I'm not sure what they are though.

Comment: The OP is trying to figure out how to get the client URL reset to a URL without the query string.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud ok, so when you get to a page with a query string, save the data to the session and redirect to the page without a query string. Your data is saved in the session.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, the OP said simply "How can I redirect to another or same page without a post, but keeping the data".  I think you assume too much.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've read that Session isn't a good way to go about it. Any other options?

Comment: @chibis I would ask you to cite your sources on that claim.

Comment: "session state takes server memory, and the information is stored until the session expires, which can be more overhead than you want for simply passing information to the next page" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @chibis Memory management is not a strong-suit of ASP.NET and C# in general. The applications I have built that rely heavily on Sessions are reliable when you do them correctly, even on lower-end servers.

Answer (score 2):

Session is an often-used mechanism to "pass" values around outside of Querystring or POST variables.

```
Session["test"] = "Test word";
string test = (string)Session["test"];
```

However, I will tell you that you should look into the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern if you want the best way to handle the situation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Basically, your main actions that update data are handled through a POST. If that is successful, you then REDIRECT to a GET, which has your querystring params in it (like "updated=True" or whatever.

When done this way, the user does not have the ability to accidentally or intentionally re-trigger the actual data saving action, because if they reload the page they land on (the GET page), no data is altered, and their confirmation message stays the same.

Comment: Correct me if I'm misunderstanding PRG, but didn't he ask for a method without a POST?

Comment: I honestly wasn't quite sure what he was asking for, but I mention PRG here just as a best-practice for going forward.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern**

In **ASP.NET**, you can use Session, as described in the answer by @gunr2171.

In **ASP.NET MVC** you can use TempData.

To support multiple screen refreshes on the final page, you can use the `TempData.Keep()` method:

```
TempData.Keep("TempDataKeyValue1");
SomeModelClass model = (SomeModelClass)TempData["TempDataKeyValue1"];
```